# Android app, give day a number

Tags: android, string, date, quote

Right I'm very noobie when it comes to Android, I have built a couple of basic applications but nothing major.

What I'm trying to do is create a quote of the day application where by when you load up the application it displays a quote (listed in a string) depending on what day of the year it is.

I have the main code for displaying a quote from a string done. and this works and I can select which quote to show by changing entries in the code or I have written some code to display the quote at random.

The next step is to display a quote depending on the date.  For this to happen I'm guessing I need to utilized the built in clock/calendar of the phone. this is where i come unstuck. I have create the local variable `daynumber` but this has to be populated somehow pulling the number from the clock.

My questions are these:

1 Am I going about this the right way. Have I got the logic right.

2 If not how would I do this

3 How would I get the phone to pull the day of the year and interpret this.

In short what I'm basically asking for is to turn a year into 365 days 1 is jan 1st, 2 is jan 2nd, 365 is dec 31st

Here is the code I have :

```
package com.quote.app;

import java.util.Random;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private String[] myString;
    private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Resources res = getResources();

        myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray); 

        String q = myString[daynumber];

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        tv.setText(q);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks, didn't know it would be so simple. literally been searching ALL evening for this.

Comment: Quick question, if I change the date manually it takes me closing the app and opening it again before it updates is there a way of as soon as the date changes it auto updates. Maybe an onresume

Comment: If you add it in onResume then it will update every time the activity is restarted (i.e. you come out of the app and in again, or change rotation). So at least you won't need to restart the whole app. The other option is to look into the Timer and TimerTask classes so you can schedule a function to be called exactly when the day changes.

Comment: Hey Jon, How would I add an onResume to my code to accomplish this. Where would it go and what would it contain

Comment: onResume is a method from the Activity base class that you want to override, just as you do with onCreate. So copy and paste your onCreate function, and rename it to onResume (also change super.onCreate to super.onResume). You want setContentView to still be in onCreate, but everything below that you can move to your onResume function.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Calendar Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_YEAR). You can get today's date with the following (taken from the reference linked)

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance()
```

You can also get the number for the current day (January 1st is 1, 2nd is 2 and so on).